# compression difference in a AS3 SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, compression, flash

I received a banner in AS3 with all the class and the SWC, the banner size is 60ko.
When I Open the fla and just republish it without modify anything, the size increase to 105ko

Is there a method to compress better a swf?
How could have done the previous developer to reach this size?

Do you have any idea, or did you have this problem already?

cheers

Comment: [Apparat](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/): best Flash compression ever.

Comment: @kinso that depend on flash IDE version are you using old flash ide make size bigger

Comment: @RIAstar : thanks i will have a look

Comment: @mgraph: i m using cs5 so i don t think there is a big difference between cs5 and cs5.5

Comment: Make sure debugging is turned off.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340866/what-is-a-flash-swc-file-and-how-is-it-used

Answer (score 2):

as @Laurent mentioned, it's probably because you're exporting all the debug symbols etc.

An ide like flashdevelop has different compile modes, debug and release, that can remove this stuff automatically for you, but you can also run your swf through the optimizer tool that's in the bin folder of the flex sdk

Answer (score 0):

Please check the settings marked in the following screenshot. These are the settings that effect the compression. Vary these to ge the best result.

[image]